# Backend для загрузки файлов при помощи Nginx upload module

Tags: apache, nginx, fileupload, php

Каким образом я могу получить дополнительные данные, которые я передаю бэкенду с Nginx на Apache?

Содержимое nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location = /upload/share {


      client_max_body_size 25000m;


      # указываем бэкенд, который выполнится уже после загрузки данных
      # это может быть ваш PHP скрипт для управления файлами
      # и директорию, куда сохраняются загруженные файлы
      upload_pass @test;
      upload_store /tmp;

      # укажем, какие дополнительные данные передать бэкенду
      upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
      upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
      upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

      upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
      upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";

      upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
      upload_limit_rate 100m;
      track_uploads upload 1m;

     }
     location @test {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:80;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php), всю информацию о загруженных файлах содержит глобальный массив [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php).